# c# access modifier section like c++

Tags: c#

Do I need to write *all* access modifiers in c#?

```
static class Node {
    Node link;//Node * link;
    int data;

    public:
        void setlink(Node next){...}
        void display(){.....}
```

I want to use access modifiers section(`public:`, `protected:`)like in c++
how can I use it?
Do I have to write all of them?

```
public void setlink(Node next){...}
public void display(){...}
```

instead

```
public:
    void setlink(Node next){....}
    void display(){....}
```

Comment: Yes, you specify it on each member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you specify it on each member. Two good things about this:

- Moving the methods around within the same class can't affect anything.
- You can *immediately* see the access modifier by looking at the method declaration. No need to look higher up in the file to see if you're in a public section or not.